# How can i access FormArray inside formGroup inside another formGroup?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have an array of data as follows:

```js
[
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "task1",
      taskForms: [
        {
          id: "8782",
          name: "ProcedureComment",
          sortOrder: null,
          description: "Comment for 'Procedure end / Suture' task",
          label: null
        },
        {
          id: "20",
          name: "form20",
          description: "form20 description",
          label: "form20 lable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "task2",
      taskForms: [
        {
          id: "87822",
          name: "ProcedureComment2",
          sortOrder: null,
          description: "Comment for 'Procedure end / Suture' task2",
          label: null
        },
        {
          id: "202",
          name: "form202",
          description: "form202 description",
          label: "form202 lable"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

and I want to convert `taskForms` to `FormArray()`.

Do I have to mark `tasks` as `formGroup` and then mark `taskForms` as `FormArray`? How do I do this?

```js
public formGroup = new FormGroup({
    tasks: new FormControl([]) 
//==>> i need it first as FormControl then i want to convert it and write data inside.
  });
```

I tried:

```js
    this.formGroup.setControl('tasks', this.formBuilder.group(tasks));
```

but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem or helped in finding the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### FormArray in Nested FormGroup

You can just use the `FormBuilder` to make your life easier:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    nested_formgroup: this.fb.group({
      array: this.fb.array([
        { example: ['']}
      ])
    })
  })
}
```

#### Result

```json
{
  "nested_formgroup": {
    "array": [
      {
        "example": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Load the Data

To load the data you will just need to map your object to the `value` members of the `FormControls`.

```js
loadData() {
  this.someService.getData().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.formGroup.get('nested_formgroup').get('array').value[0].example = data.example
    }
  )
}
```

Here's an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdh41b?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you to test/play with.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and the example in stackblitz. 

I want to fill this form group with data. 

If I do this.formgroup.setValue(myDataArray) there’s something goes wrong and controls are empty. 

Could you please complete your example and fill the formgroup with data